# Can an SSL cert (not self-signed) be used to create another SSL cert for another host in the same domain?

Tags: networking, security, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a regular SSL certificate issued by Network Solutions for a given host, say "host A". Can I create another SSL cert for the wiki host that has the host A cert in its trust path and therefore works for use on the wiki host? Both hosts are in the same domain, for example:

a.host.com <- host A uses purchased SSL cert; CA is Network Solutions

wiki.host.com <- needs its own cert

This question is based on my assumption that since I own a trusted cert from a trusted CA for my domain, then I should be able to use that cert to make others for other hosts on the same domain and those new certs should be trusted since they record the "trust path" up to a trusted CA.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

From a technical standpoint, you can use the certificate with the common name a.host.com to sign the certificate for wiki.host.com, so in that sense, "yes".

However, nobody has your a.host.com certificate in their trusted CA list, so you're not actually accomplishing anything that you wouldn't with a purely self-signed certificate. So in that sense, "no", or at least, "not usefully".

If your question is "will browsers trust your a.host.com certificate's signatures of other certificates?" the answer is no, they will not. (The fact that they are in the same domain doesn't change anything here, either.)

Comment: I edited the Q to add last paragraph. thx

Comment: And my answer still stands; that's not how trust paths work. The CA has warranted that you are who you say you are, not that you can be trusted to sign other certificates.

Comment: Ya, I wasn't arguing... just trying to help.